# scp current folder to destination folder name as ddmmyy

Tags: scp

I want to add a cron job that scp a folder to a server with on the server the folder name is in another folder whose folder name is a timestamp like ddmmyy

something like

```
scp -r <foldername> user@server:path/to/destination/ddmmyyhhmmss
```

ddmmyyhhmmss: date month year hour min sec

Comment: And what is the problem? Of course your 'path/to/destination' must exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the date via the date command which lets you specify a date format via %d, %m, etc.  Cron treats % characters as special so you need to escape them.  Something like this should copy your file at the top of every hour.

```
0   *   *   *   *   scp -r <foldername> user@server:path/to/destination/$(date +\%d\%m\%y\%H\%M\%S)
```